# How to reload unsaved Sublime Text 3 tabs from an auto-save session file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

For the past 3+ years, I've had some unsaved Sublime Text 3 files (tabs) that would load automatically when I restarted my machine.

Today, I noticed that all of the unsaved tabs are "gone".

I see a file named `Backup Auto Save Session.sublime_session` in the directory `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local`.  When I inspect this file, I see that everything that had previously been in the respective tabs is now stored in 26,000 lines of JSON.  So, that's a good start!

But, how do I ***use*** this auto-save session file to reload all of the approximately 20 unsaved tabs? Is it possible to point to this session file when the app launches?

Or, am I stuck just trying to reconstruct each of the tabs manually using the large JSON file?

My OS is Windows 10.  The Sublime Text build is 4169.

Thanks!

Comment: While Sublime's not running, rename the `Session.sublime-session` to something else, then duplicate your backup and rename it to be `Session.sublime-session` and restart Sublime